# Google Cloud Platform Storage Java SDK Security

Tags: security, https, google-cloud-platform

Is GCP Storage Java SDK secured when accessing to public buckets, in regard to HTTPS, MITM, etc?
There's no authentication required in the process.

Answer (score 1):

The only layer of security available is to set permissions on the buckets Using [Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions) . This will give control over who has access to your buckets and objects.